# Python pyspark validate if column is null

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to python databricks.
I'm trying to validate a csv file which is in ADSL.
I'm validating a column in the csv file, if the column contains null or empty or no value, it should write the file to reject folder or if it is not null it should write to some other folder.
I dont see any error in the below code, but the issue here is the values in the column are not getting validated. Could someone please help here
Below is the code.

```
adls_account_name="**ADLS**"
adls_account_key="***"
blob_account_name="**blob**"
blob_account_key="**"
spark.conf.set(
"fs.azure.account.key."+adls_account_name+".dfs.core.windows.net",adls_account_key)
spark.conf.set(
"fs.azure.account.key."+blob_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",blob_account_key)

fileName="abfss://container@adls.dfs.core.windows.net/DataCollection/EmployeeData/2021/May/26/Temp_employees.csv"
df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferschema","true").load(fileName)

if 'employee_id' in df.columns:
  if df['employee_id'].isNotNull:

    target_folder_path="abfss://container@adls.dfs.core.windows.net/ValidatedFiles/" 
    df=df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(target_folder_path) 
    
  else:
  
    reject_folder_path="wasbs://blobfolder@blob.blob.core.windows.net/"                                    
    df=df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(reject_folder_path)                                                  
                                   
else:
  print("column not found")
```

Comment: One problem: `isNotNull` is a function, and you forgot the parenthesis to call the function.  Another problem: You won't be able to say `if df['employee_id'].isNotNull():` - you need to use something like [`df.filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter).

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for responding. If you could help me with the full syntax, it'll be useful to me to learn more.

Comment: pyspark, by default, does not do a row-by-row processing. so, your `if df['employee_id'].isNotNull()` won't work as it seems you want it to. there are many ways to check this - you can check the df using your condition (e.g. - count the number of rows where emp id is null) and then store the output which is then used for the `if` - just throwing some ideas.